# Azure pipeline trigger a branch that doesn't contain the same pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is there a way to get a yaml pipeline like this to trigger even when the triggering branch doesn't contain the same pipeline yaml file?

**Pipeline:**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - test
      - test2
```

The "test" branch would contain the yaml pipeline, and the "test2" would not contain the pipeline.

I'm trying to use one branch in the repo that would be for all the pipelines, so one doesn't have to always modify the pipelines in each branch and maintain them.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a yaml pipeline like this to trigger even when
> the triggering branch doesn't contain the same pipeline yaml file?

For this issue, if the triggering branch does not contain the same pipeline yaml file, I am afraid that it is impossible to trigger the same yaml pipeline. Branches can only trigger the yaml pipelines corresponding to the pipeline yaml file they contain.

For example, if the "test" branch contains the azure-pipelines.yml file, but the "test2" branch does not contain any azure-pipelines.yml file, you will get the following error message when you switch to the "test2" branch on the pipeline page.

[image]

> I'm trying to use one branch in the repo that would be for all the
> pipelines

You can add multiple yaml pipeline files to a branch. When creating pipelines, you only need to select the corresponding yaml files, so that one branch can be used for all pipelines.

[image]